# Fixed width table columns in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap 3 for a backend application, this application shows data in tables. At the end of each row there is a delete button (and sometimes also a edit button).

I use col-md-1 for the column that has the delete button, and variations of col-md-x on the other columns, works fine.

One thing that bugs me is that when i enlarge my browser window the col-md-1 column becomes huge, makes sense because of bootstrap grid design. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

But it still bugs me every time i look at it.

Is it possible to give a column a fixed width, for example 32 pixels, while keep using the col-md-x feature of bootstrap which i really enjoy?

[edit] maybe a clarification: I'm looking for a maximum width, for example min width 32 and max width 32, then the column should not grow wider than 32 px and shouldn't shrink to less than 32 px.

Comment: It's possible to do that.

Comment: @Christina that's nice to hear, but the question is how?

Comment: if 2 col are 50px wide, put a class on both th and make the width:50px with a custom class then on the 2 closest col-X-X find the width, say it's 25% (col-X-3) write css that re-declares that width minus 50px (calc) -- this would be done in the media query.

Comment: @Christina That sounds complicated, but i think i get the idea, you'll get different widths based on the browser width.

Comment: It's very easy but since you have not put a full example up of your situation, I'm not going to create it for you.

Comment: @Christina no need for an example, will soon dive into media queries, sounds interesting!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 .tdicon{ width: 32px !important; }
```

This doesn't work:

```
<th class="col-md-6"></th>
<th class="col-md-2"></th>
<th class="col-md-4"></th>
<th class="tdicon">&nbsp;</th>
<th class="tdicon">&nbsp;</th>
```

But this works:

```
<th class="col-md-6"></th>
<th class="col-md-2"></th>
<th></th>
<th class="tdicon">&nbsp;</th>
<th class="tdicon">&nbsp;</th>
```

Now the tdicon column becomes 32 px and stays 32 px after resizing. Weird!

I'm happy that is works, but the solution confuses me...

Comment: Did you mean to not close the <th> tags? That will invalidate your HTML

Comment: @MattLambert they are closed in my app, didn't want to over complicate my reply by pasting all the code, there is a lot of stuff in the th. But I've edited and added the </th> , just to be correct ;-) Actually still not using my own solution, cause it doesn't make much sense to me... I'll have to dive into bootstrap mechanics on a free evening and see why this works.

Comment: It probably works because the class-less `th` is allowed to have whatever size, while the `col-md-*` columns are locked to a percentage. however, why don't you just put your icons in one column and place them in a div with `pull-right`?

Answer (score 0):

it's possible, make your own class in css and define whatever you want and use it with the Column class, for example....

```
<div class="col-md-1 your-class-here">define some data</div>
```

use the above strategy, hope it will solve the issue...

Comment: Cheers for the suggestion, but i already tried that, but i gave it another shot. But it doesn't seem to work, i use .tdicon{ width: 32px !important; }, on the td and on the th, but column still grows. I even tried directly in the td like "td width=32". I suspect this specifies a minimum width, not the maximum width? In the past i solved it by using 100% on 1 td and 32px on the other columns, but with bootstrap that doesn't make much sense.

Comment: try removing the grid class then a custom class with a fixed width

Comment: if you are using pure bootstrap icon then mix it with [link](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/)  This.

Comment: @MattLambert thanks for the idea, i gave it a shot but didn't work. But it gave me a idea, see my answer.